# Изменение массива в цикле по ссылке C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Имеется ли в C# возможность изменять исходный массив или коллекцию в цикле по ссылке по аналогии с &$value в PHP?

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) 
{
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

Код на C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> arr1 = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"};

        foreach(string el in arr1)
        {
            el = "four";
        }

        arr1.Dump();
    }
}
```

Comment: массив сам по себе ссылочный тип, можно менять значение элемента без проблем в процессе итерации. Только не нужно менять при этом саму коллекцию (добавлять или удалять)

Comment: Да вот что-то на выходе исходная коллекция. Добавил код в исходное сообщение.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VYXL1E

Comment: @andrey.t, используй входной параметр ref у параметра в функции, и при вызове данной функции

Comment: Не помогло. В самом цикле foreach (TMC item in items.TMCs) не происходит изменение исходной коллекции items.

Comment: dotnetfiddle.net/VYXL1E – Sultanov Shamil . Для List<T> как-то можно это использовать?

Comment: Возможно вы имеете ввиду оператор `out` ? Прочитайте о нем.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

for(var i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
    x[i] = 2321;
```

Так пойдет?

Comment: Ну т.е. только по ключу можно. По ссылке нельзя. Так?

Comment: @andrey.t, ну в моем понимании это так. когда ты используешь конструкцию foreach, наследуешься от класса IEnumerable(точнее, list уже наследован от него, раз ты имеешь право перечислять элементы list) и его метод GetEnumerator(), который за каждый проход возвращает следующий элемент из коллекции методом MoveNext(), и ты просто его получаешь как бы в отдельной переменной, которая вообще не знает про ту коллекцию. Получается, что да, только по ключу.

Comment: @andrey.t, получается, ты просто там переменную создаешь внутри цикла и этой переменной что то вписываешь, но это никуда не присвоится внутри list.